# Nth Fibonacci number

Tags: python-3.x

I am failed to print only the nth fibonacci number.
In my code, when the user said to print nth trem it print the series upto nth term but i want to get  the output only the nth term
e.g 
if I say num=4
out put should be 2

please guide

here is the code:

```
N= int(input("How many terms? "))


N1 = 0
N2 = 1
sum = 2


if N <= 0:
   print("Plese enter a positive integer")
elif N == 1:
   print("Fibonacci sequence:")
   print(N1)
else:
   print("Fibonacci sequence:")
   print(N1,",",N2,end=' , ')
   while sum < N:
       Nth = N1 + N2
       print(Nth,end=' , ')

       N1 = N2
       N2 = Nth
       sum += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

The print stmt should be outside the loop

```
N= int(input("How many terms? "))


N1 = 0
N2 = 1
sum = 2


if N <= 0:
   print("Plese enter a positive integer")
elif N == 1:
   print("Fibonacci sequence:")
   print(N1)
else:
   print("Fibonacci sequence:")
   print(N1,",",N2,end=' , ')
   while sum < N:
       Nth = N1 + N2

       N1 = N2
       N2 = Nth
       sum += 1
   print(Nth,end=' , ')
```

Answer (score 0):

Simpler code, from the ["How to Think Like a Comptuer Scientist: Python"](http://www.greenteapress.com/thinkpython/thinkpython.pdf) book,

```
def fibonacci (n):
    if n == 0:
        return 0
    elif n == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2)
```

Just call fibonacci passing your nth term as the argument.

Answer (score 0):

to achieve that output you can simply decrease the value of n by 1 and then carry on all the computation.
For example:

```
def fib(n):
    n = n-1
    a, b = 0, 1
    count = 1
    while count <= abs(n):
        next = a + b
        a = b
        b = next
        count += 1
    return a
```